# Nginx+Memcached+Apache Vs Apache+Memcached

Tags: php, nginx, apache2, memcached

I have been reading about this for a while but couldn't find anything that directly address this issue. I want to know if it would be better to use Apache2 with worker MPM for dynamic content + Memcached for delivering static content OR Apache2 + Memcached + Ngnix.The site is built using Php. Would Nginx add any value to efficiency. I want to set up a server for heavy traffic.

Comment: get rid of apache totally and move to nginx unless you're on a 100k hits an hour upwards even a modest server will be more than capable of serving the entire site from a single nginx instance hell chances are you don't even need memcached either and could survive with just mysql back end

Comment: Thanks for the response Dave. 100k per hour is what we are looking at :) What do you suggest in that case ? Nginx is reportedly slowER than apache with dynamic content even with FastCGI.

Comment: nginx with php content is faster than apache in almost all instances. cherokee is faster still but not developed as much unfortunately as I much prefer cherokee than nginx.  Other things to consider is shipping your static content onto another instance of nginx or cherokee or whatever running on a different port.  Having said that I have 2 sites both with about 250k page views an hour and I still run it all on apache + mysql + memcached

Comment: Thanks you. I guess i'll stick to apache+memcached then. Since the site is already running on apache and i wouldnt need any configurations for many modules of php to make them work with nginx. Bw could you suggest a link for server tuning in that case.

Comment: one of my engineers does that for me but google should provide enough info for you.  I would move any static images off your apache server onto an nginx server running on a different port though but that should only take about 10 minutes to implement.